# xpath test element for class

Tags: xpath

I'm wondering if xpath has a way to test an element for a class. I currently have the ID, I would just like to be able to test to ensure JS added a class.

My element where I'm testing to see if id=foo contains class=red.

```
<span id="foo" class="red">test</span>
```

I'm assuming you would use xpathCount?

```
getXpathCount(("//a[@id='foo']") not sure what goes next).equals(1);
```

I've also tried this without success,

```
getXpathCount("//span[@id='foo'].span[contains(@class,'red')]").equals(1);
```

Comment: Your attempt `//span[@id='foo'].span[contains(@class,'red')]` is pretty close... `//span[@id='foo'][contains(@class,'red')]` would work (but would also match a span with `class="credit"` etc.)

Comment: @LarsH why would it match class credit? I'm a little lost.

Comment: `contains(@class, 'red')` means that the value of the `class` attribute *contains* the string `red`. So this is true when class holds any string with `red` as a substring, e.g. `fred`, `redone`, `reddit`, `scared`, etc. If you want to detect the case where the value of the `class` attribute *is* `red`, then use `@class = 'red'` (as Gaby wrote).

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't put two and two together that credit had red within it. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The xpath to use would be

```
//a[@id='foo' and @class='red']
```

Comment: so no need to use . to select the current element?

Comment: @George: the evaluation of an XPath expression starts from the context node ("current element") anyway, so there is no need to explicitly put `./` on the front of the expression.

Comment: So what if there are more than one classes to an element and I need just one of them to be red (I am using lxml BTW, not sure if implementation should matter)